# How to access parts of AWS Lambda event in F#?

Tags: amazon-web-services, f#, aws-lambda

I am moving some code from Python to F# and I was wondering how could I access the same information like before.

Python code:

```
request_http_method = event.get('requestContext', {}).get('httpMethod', 'none')
```

F# code:

```
open Amazon.Lambda.Core
open FSharp.Data

[<assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof<Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer>)>]

do ()

type Request = { requestContext : string; }
```

I need to create a type for each part of the event or there is a way to access these fields with Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are types already available for each of the events that lambda can handle, including the APIGateway events, you'll need to add this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="1.2.0" />
```

and you can use it like this:

```
open Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents
open Amazon.Lambda.Core
open FSharp.Data

[<assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof<Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer>)>]

do ()

module Handler =

    let hello(request:APIGatewayProxyRequest) =
        let method = request.HttpMethod
        APIGatewayProxyResponse(StatusCode = 200, Body = request.Body)
```